# JDBC connection to remote oracle database does not work in jdk 7 and 8, but it works in jdk 6?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

Please find the code below.I get the connection only with jdk 6 with ojdbc6.jar.

In jdk 7 and 8 , I get,

> network adaptor could not establish connection error and connection
>   timeout

The remote oracle database runs on Oracle 11g.

```
try {

                    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver");

                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {

                    System.out.println("Where is your Oracle JDBC Driver?");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return;

                }

                System.out.println("Oracle JDBC Driver Registered!");

                Connection connection = null;

                try {


                    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=abcd.efg)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=OW_DEF)))","user","pwd#");
                } catch (SQLException e) {

                    System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return;

                }

                if (connection != null) {
                    System.out.println("You made it, take control your database now!");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");
                }
```

Comment: Which version of the Oracle JDBC driver are you using (full version, please)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, your `ojdbc6.jar` might be older version.

Refer [this page](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/apps-tech/jdbc-112010-090769.html) , there are drivers jars named - `ojdbc6.jar` which wouldn't work for JDK 7 & 8, only version - **11.2.0.4** is mentioned to be **Certified with JDK 8, JDK 7 and JDK 6**.

You can check your driver version using methods described [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/csoto/checking-the-oracle-jdbc-driver-version-on-a-weblogic-server)

I find command - `java -jar ojdbc6.jar -getversion` more convenient.

Replace jar name with your jar name ( if name on your local is different ).

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply.I tried with the jar you mentioned,still the same error.

Comment: You can try a commercial [Oracle JDBC driver](https://www.progress.com/jdbc/oracle-database) from DataDirect that works across multiple Oracle and JRE versions to isolate the issue from being related to your network/database. Note: I am employed by Progress.